# R: Combine multiple columns as pairs of column cells in same row

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I'd like to combine/pair multiple columns in a data frame as pairs of column cells in the same row. As an example, `df1` should be transformed to `df2`.

`df1`

```
col1 col2 col3
1    2    3   
0    0    1
```

`df2`

```
c1  c2
1    2
1    3
2    3
0    0
0    1
0    1
```

The solution should be scalable for `df1`s with (way) more than three columns.

I thought about melt/reshape/dcast but found no solution yet. There are no NAs in the data frame. Thank you!

EDIT: `Reshape` just produced errors, so I thought about

`combn(df1[1,], 2)
comb2 <- t(comb1)`

and looping and appending through all rows. This inefficient, considering 2 million rows..

Comment: I am new to R and thus not very literate, but I've tried reshape to transform it into long format. However, I can't find a way to only pair two of the columns at a point..

Comment: Please include the code from your attempt in your question.

Comment: Thank you - I've included it.

Comment: `Reshape just produced errors` -- that's not code though. Wouldn't you like to understand *why* what you were trying was producing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit is very similar to my answer below, you just need to rbind the result each iteration over the rows of df1. Using data.table is a good way to speed up rbind, [see this answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697700/how-to-speed-up-rbind).

EDIT: Unfortunately, when I switched to the data.table approach, it turned out that the rbindlist() led the answer to be wrong (as pointed out in the comment below). Therefore, although it may be slightly slower, I think that preallocating a data frame and using rbind may be the best option.

EDIT2: switched the preallocated df to a more general number of rows.

```
df1 = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,0,0,1,1), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2))
nrow_combn = nrow(t(combn(df1[1,], m = 2)))
nrow_df = nrow(df1) * nrow_combn
df2 = data.frame(V1 = rep(0, nrow_df), V2 = rep(0, nrow_df))
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  df2[(((i-1)*nrow_combn)+1):(i*(nrow_combn)), ] = data.frame(t(combn(df1[i,], m = 2)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I've tried your approach but the result is not the desired one: It produces 2 rows and six columns, simply duplicating each cell's element. I don't know why since the basic `t(combn(...` solution yields the right result, but just for one row at a time.

Comment: Growing an object will likely by slow no matter which tool user uses.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik did you read the link I posted? In that simulation, this approach was faster than pre-allocating a data frame.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, @AndyMcKenzie! It works for this example, but it is not possible to scale b/c of `nrow_df = ncol(df1) * nrow(df1)`. For instance, having four columns in the initial sample would yield 4 choose 2=6 combinations per row, making it 12 in total, while the code just creates 8.

Comment: EDIT: A fix might be `nrow_df5 <- choose(ncol(df1),2) * nrow(df1)`. I'll try this now.

Comment: @user5835099 Thanks for pointing that out; hopefully the current answer is more general.

Comment: Not sure what you tried with "data.table", but it's certainly doable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach I would take.

Create a function that uses `rbindlist` from "data.table" and `combn` from base R. The function looks like this:

```
lengthener <- function(indf) {
  temp <- rbindlist(
    combn(names(indf), 2, FUN = function(x) indf[x], simplify = FALSE),
    use.names = FALSE, idcol = TRUE)
  setorder(temp[, .id := sequence(.N), by = .id], .id)[, .id := NULL][]
}
```

Here's the sample data from the other answer, and the application of the function on it:

```
df1 = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,0,0,1,1), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2))

lengthener(df1)
#     V1 V2
#  1:  1  2
#  2:  1  3
#  3:  1  4
#  4:  2  3
#  5:  2  4
#  6:  3  4
#  7:  0  0
#  8:  0  1
#  9:  0  1
# 10:  0  1
# 11:  0  1
# 12:  1  1
```

Test it out on some larger data too:

```
set.seed(1)
M <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(100, 100*100, TRUE), 100))
system.time(out <- lengthener(M))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.19    0.00    0.19 
out
#         V1 V2
#      1: 27 66
#      2: 27 27
#      3: 27 68
#      4: 27 66
#      5: 27 56
#     ---      
# 494996: 33 13
# 494997: 33 66
# 494998: 80 13
# 494999: 80 66
# 495000: 13 66
```

---

System time for the other approach:

```
funAMK <- function(indf) {
  nrow_combn = nrow(t(combn(indf[1,], m = 2)))
  nrow_df = nrow(indf) * nrow_combn
  df2 = data.frame(V1 = rep(0, nrow_df), V2 = rep(0, nrow_df))
  for(i in 1:nrow(indf)){
    df2[(((i-1)*nrow_combn)+1):(i*(nrow_combn)), ] = data.frame(t(combn(indf[i,], m = 2)))
  }
  df2
}

> system.time(funAMK(M))
   user  system elapsed 
  16.03    0.16   16.37
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ananda Mahto! I've already been working successfully with the other answer above but appreciate your effort!

Comment: @user5835099, no problem. Just FYI, I've added this [as a function](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/lengthener.R) in [my SOfun package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun). The `lengthener()` function lets you specify the "n" for the `combn` as well. My answer was mostly to show how some more efficiency could be achieved if needed and because Andy wasn't able to get the code working with "data.table".