# R: Is there a good replacement for plyr::rbind.fill in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

for tidyverse users, dplyr is the new way to work with data.

For users trying to avoid older package plyr, what is the equivalent function to rbind.fill in dplyr?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes. `dplyr::bind_rows`

Credit goes to commenter.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
rbindf <- function(...) {
  
  l <- list(...)
  if(length(l) == 1) l <- l[[1]]
  nn <- length(l)

  x <- l[[1]]
  if(length(l)>1){
      for(i in 2:nn) {
        y <- l[[i]]
        if(nrow(x) > 0 & nrow(y) > 0) {
          if(!all(yinx <- names(y) %in% names(x))) {
            x[, names(y)[!yinx]] <- NA
          } 
          if(!all(xiny <- names(x) %in% names(y))) {
             y[, names(x)[!xiny]] <- NA
          } 
        }
        x <- rbind(x, y)
      }
  }
  return(x)
}
```

From https://github.com/sashahafner/biogas (originally from https://github.com/jonkatz2/monitoR).

Answer (score 0):

Same Thing with R Base:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(6:10))
df3 <- data.frame(a = c(11:15), b = c(16:20), c = LETTERS[1:5])
df2[setdiff(names(df3), names(df2))] <- NA
df3[setdiff(names(df2), names(df3))] <- NA

rbind(df2, df3)
```