# Replacement of plyr::cbind.fill in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, cbind

I apologize if this question is elementary, but I've been scouring the internet and I can't seem to find a simple solution.

I currently have a list of R objects (named vectors or dataframes of 1 variable, I can work with either), and I want to join them into 1 large dataframe with 1 row for each unique name/rowname, and 1 column for each element in the original list.

My starting list looks something like:

```
l1 <- list(df1 = data.frame(c(1,2,3), row.names = c("A", "B", "C")), 
       df2 = data.frame(c(2,6), row.names = c("B", "D")),
       df3 = data.frame(c(3,6,9), row.names = c("C", "D", "A")),
       df4 = data.frame(c(4,12), row.names = c("A", "E")))
```

And I want the output to look like:

```
data.frame("df1" = c(1,2,3,NA,NA),
+            "df2" = c(NA,2,NA,6,NA),
+            "df3" = c(9,NA,3,6,NA),
+            "df4" = c(4,NA,NA,NA,12), row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
  df1 df2 df3 df4
A   1  NA   9   4
B   2   2  NA  NA
C   3  NA   3  NA
D  NA   6   6  NA
E  NA  NA  NA  12
```

I don't mind if the fill values are NA or 0 (ultimately I want 0 but that's an easy fix).

I'm almost positive that `plyr::cbind.fill` does exactly this, but I have been using dplyr in the rest of my script and I don't think using both is a good idea. `dplyr::bind_cols` does not seem to work with vectors of different lengths. I'm aware a very similar question has been asked here: [R: Is there a good replacement for plyr::rbind.fill in dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464441/r-is-there-a-good-replacement-for-plyrrbind-fill-in-dplyr)
but as I mentioned, this solution doesn't actually seem to work. Neither does `dplyr::full_join`, even wrapped in a `do.call`. Is there a straightforward solution to this, or is the only solution to write a custom function?

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, but since you put a vector inside `data.frame` with no name, you've got messy names like `c.1..2..3.`

Comment: @camille I did notice that, this isn't the case in my actual data. The list elements start out as just named vectors, but I can easily coerce them to dataframes of 1 variable, and the column name ends up being identical to the corresponding list element name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way with some `purrr` and `dplyr` functions. Create column names to represent each data frame—since each has only one column, this is easy with `setNames`, but with more columns you could use `dplyr::rename`. Do a full-join across the whole list based on the original row names, and fill `NA`s with 0.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

l1 %>%
  imap(~setNames(.x, .y)) %>%
  map(tibble::rownames_to_column) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "rowname") %>%
  mutate_all(tidyr::replace_na, 0)
#>   rowname df1 df2 df3 df4
#> 1       A   1   0   9   4
#> 2       B   2   2   0   0
#> 3       C   3   0   3   0
#> 4       D   0   6   6   0
#> 5       E   0   0   0  12
```

Answer (score 7):

We can convert the rownames to a column with `rownames_to_column`, then `rename` the second column, bind the `list` elements with `bind_rows`, and reshape to 'wide' with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
map_dfr(l1, ~ rownames_to_column(.x, 'rn') %>% 
              rename_at(2, ~'v1'), .id = 'grp') %>%        
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = v1) %>% 
   column_to_rownames('rn')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I've done wrong or if it's just my institution's outdated version of RStudio, but I'm getting `Error in pivot_wider(., names_from = grp, values_from = v1) : 
  could not find function "pivot_wider"`

Comment: @Tom Can you please check your `tidyr` version.  It is available from 1.0.0

Comment: I really like this approach! One minor thing: using `purrr::map_dfr()` you can skip the `bind_rows()` The line would look like this: `map_dfr(l1, ~ rownames_to_column(.x, 'rn') %>% 2, ~'v1'), .id = 'grp')`

Comment: @Till Thank you.  I forgot about that.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another `purrr` and `dplyr` option could be:

```
l1 %>%
 map2_dfr(.x = ., .y = names(.), ~ setNames(.x, .y) %>%
           rownames_to_column()) %>%
 group_by(rowname) %>%
 summarise_all(~ ifelse(all(is.na(.)), NA, first(na.omit(.))))

  rowname   df1   df2   df3   df4
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A           1    NA     9     4
2 B           2     2    NA    NA
3 C           3    NA     3    NA
4 D          NA     6     6    NA
5 E          NA    NA    NA    12
```