# More efficiency creating a new variable using for loop

Tags: r, performance

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do this since I have a millions-long dataset that has been stuck for days in this step.

```
for (i in 1:32000000){
    if (!exists("df")){
     df <- as.data.frame(Properties[[i]])
     df <- as.data.frame(t(df))
   }else{
     temp_dataset <- as.data.frame(Properties[[i]])
     temp_dataset <- as.data.frame(t(temp_dataset))
     df <- rbind(df, temp_dataset)
      rm(temp_dataset)
   }
}
```

Basically what is doing is to create a new variable and add new rows as the variable `i` progress through `1:32000000`. But, as I said it takes a lot of time so I need a more efficient way to do it.

`Properties` looks like:

```
List of 32000000
 $ : Named num [1:3] -0.85 -0.544 0.208
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "PP1" "PP2" "PP3"
 $ : Named num [1:3] -0.332 -0.698 0.264
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "PP1" "PP2" "PP3"
 $ : Named num [1:3] -0.768 -0.486 0.184
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "PP1" "PP2" "PP3"
 $ : Named num [1:3] -0.458 -0.57 -0.054
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "PP1" "PP2" "PP3"
 $ : Named num [1:3] -0.536 -0.458 0.348
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "PP1" "PP2" "PP3"
 $ : Named num [1:3] -0.47 -0.776 0.06
```

Comment: Maybe `do.call(rbind, Properties)` ?

Comment: In case `rbind` is still to slow have a look at [How to speed up rbind?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19697700/10488504)

Comment: @GKi in this case that linked solution will not work, because this is a list of vectors not a list of data frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way will be using `rbind` in `do.call`.

```
do.call(rbind, Properties)
```

Benchmark: (Based on @Adam)

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e5
Properties <- replicate(n, setNames(runif(3), c("PP1", "PP2", "PP3")), simplify = FALSE)

bench::mark(check = FALSE
       , dplyr = dplyr::bind_rows(Properties)
       , rbind = do.call(rbind, Properties)
       , data.table = setNames(data.table::transpose(Properties),
                                              names(Properties[[1]]))
       , unlist = matrix(unlist(Properties, FALSE, FALSE),
                         ncol=length(Properties[[1]]), byrow=TRUE,
                         dimnames = list(NULL, names(Properties[[1]])))
       )
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 dplyr        1.53s   1.53s     0.652    8.78MB    10.4      1    16      1.53s
#2 rbind      74.19ms 86.81ms     6.92     2.29MB     3.46     4     2    578.4ms
#3 data.table  4.31ms  5.28ms   185.       4.58MB    12.0     93     6   501.56ms
#4 unlist       2.8ms  3.38ms   256.       4.58MB    22.0    128    11   500.31ms

#All have to return the same
bench::mark(
         dplyr = as.matrix(dplyr::bind_rows(Properties))
       , rbind = do.call(rbind, Properties)
       , data.table = do.call(cbind, setNames(data.table::transpose(Properties),
                                              names(Properties[[1]])))
       , unlist = matrix(unlist(Properties, FALSE, FALSE),
                         ncol=length(Properties[[1]]), byrow=TRUE,
                         dimnames = list(NULL, names(Properties[[1]])))
       )
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 dplyr        1.49s   1.49s     0.673   11.06MB     8.75     1    13      1.49s
#2 rbind      73.26ms 87.91ms     7.68     2.29MB     5.12     6     4   781.51ms
#3 data.table  4.95ms   5.7ms   166.       6.87MB    19.7     84    10   507.06ms
#4 unlist      3.02ms  3.35ms   276.       4.58MB    32.0    138    16    500.4ms
```

In this case using `unlist` and `matrix` is the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `transpose()` from `data.table`. This should be pretty fast.

Sample data:

```r
n <- 100000

Properties <- replicate(n, setNames(runif(3), c("PP1", "PP2", "PP3")), simplify = FALSE)

head(Properties, 3)

# [[1]]
#       PP1       PP2       PP3 
# 0.8036237 0.9423731 0.9593770 
# 
# [[2]]
#       PP1       PP2       PP3 
# 0.1906879 0.5571697 0.9718734 
# 
# [[3]]
#       PP1       PP2       PP3 
# 0.7542362 0.3420677 0.4541527
```

Stacking code:

```r
df <- as.data.frame(data.table::transpose(Properties),
                    col.names = c("PP1", "PP2", "PP3"))
```

Benchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  do.call = do.call(rbind, Properties),
  data.table = as.data.frame(data.table::transpose(Properties),
                             col.names = c("PP1", "PP2", "PP3")))

# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr     min       lq       mean   median        uq      max neval
#     do.call 74.2183 83.29040 107.001017 96.63925 113.61070 322.4556   100
#  data.table  4.6864  5.06845   6.163916  5.30285   5.56845  73.3627   100
```